# Is it possible to create a "virtual" symlink in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-registry, symbolic-link, redirection, folder-redirection

Let's say I've got this directory structure:

```
.
├── Documents
│   ├── Finance
│   ├── School
│   ├── Skyrim
│   ├── Work
└── Saved Games
    ├── Fallout
    └── Minecraft
```

The folders `Skyrim`, `Fallout`, and `Minecraft` are created by their respective games, and as such cannot be moved as they'll just be created again next time the game launches.

I'd like to get everything in to "Saved Games", but I don't want to create a bunch of symlinks within Documents, as then those symlinks would still clutter up that folder.

What I'd like to do instead is to tell Windows that when requesting "Documents/Skyrim," it should redirect to "Saved Games/Skyrim" instead, without having an actual symlink file in "Documents."

I'm thinking of this as a kind of "301 redirect" in an `.htaccess` in web terms. The file you're redirecting doesn't actually have to exist for the server to send the request to the updated location. I'm imagining that this may be possible with a registry key or the like.

Is this possible, or would I have to have actual symlink files within "Documents?"

---

EDIT: @music2myear asked for a bit more context as to why I'm wanting to do this.

I sync my "user" folders via OneDrive, and I'd like my "Documents" folder to be only contain the actual *documents* that I need, and not random system files that things like games (just one example) tend to throw in there. I could easily create some symlinks, but I don't think that's going to solve the issue, as they'll still be in the OneDrive directory and therefore still get uploaded.

I'll try and do a bit of testing today (2019-05-31) to verify that these proposed solutions won't work.

Comment: Is your interest aesthetic or practical? In short, WHY do you want this to not be a real symlink with a file and everything?

Comment: @music2myear sure thing, added context to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a workaround, but the only option I'm aware of:
If I were you, I would just make hidden symlinks.

So the folder doesn't look that overcrowded.

Comment: That's what I suspected; unfortunately I don't think that'll work well for my purposes, though. I'm trying to clean up my Dropbox's "Documents" folder (which I symlink to my system Documents folder), so I think creating a bunch of hidden directories would still sync them up. I'll try it out though and report back if it works for my use case.